# Different "grid-template-columns" values for mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way
to have different "grid-template-columns" values
for mobile and desktop.

**i want it to look in mobile like this.**

[image]

**and in desktop like this.**

[image]

so with media query we can change main element's grid-template-columns in this html sample

**mobile look can be achieved with**

> grid-template-columns: 1fr;

**desktop look can be achieved with**

> grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;

but is there a more clever way to do this in just css without media query definitions?

i want to arrange grid-template-columns dynamically. What are my options?

**please check this my code.**

```css
html {
  font-size: 15px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-block: 2rem;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

menu,
section,
div {
  margin-block: 1rem;
}

div {
  padding-inline: 1rem;
}

a {
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(21rem, 1fr));
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Site Title</h1>

<main>
  <menu>
    <a>link</a>
    <a>other link</a>
  </menu>
  <section>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <h2>caption 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <h2>caption 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <h2>caption 3</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Nope, that's what media queries are for.

Comment: It's unclear what you're wanting when you say "more clever". You want to "outsmart" the intended, supported mechanism for achieving some thing?

Comment: yes, i'm thinking how do i do it differently